# Consecutive Integers in Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation, order-theory

I'm trying to optimize the performance of a particular program, and I think the solution might exist in the form of a mathematic formula that I'm trying to identify.

#### Description of the problem:

I've built a program that can take a RummiKub hand of tiles (each tile being comprised of a color and a number). One of the constraints of a valid solution is that every Run that can be made with the hand of tiles must be comprised of tiles whose numbers can be arranged into consecutive order.

#### Current (functional) solution:

I determine whether this constraint is met by sorting the list of tile numbers in descending order, and checking to see that as I go down the list, each number is exactly one less than the one preceding it.

#### Better solution I'm looking for:

My current solution has an (admittedly negligible) impact on performance.

I'm attempting to check this constraint by finding some unique relationship between the sum of a set of integers and the number of integers in the set. That way I can keep a running sum of the tile numbers, and when it comes time to check it's validity I can apply this relationship property to the sum and the number of tiles and determine if the list is made of consecutive integers.

*Is there such a relationship that I can use for this purpose?*

Comment: $2+3=1+4$ would seem to show that what you want can't be done.

Comment: I think you're correct, but I'd really like to be wrong about that. There are ways you can be relatively confident that the set is consecutive - for instance if the set is ordered you can take the average of the first and last items, and multiply it by the number of items, and compare it to the sum - if the two values are equal, then a lot of times this is an indicator that the list is consecutively ordered. It does fail when lists are just *barely* not consecutively ordered though - which tells me there's some room between needing to count all of them and only needing to count some of them.

Comment: The sets $\{1,12\},\{2,11\},\{3,10\},\dots,\{6,7\}$ all have the same average of 1st & last terms, all have the same number of items, all have the same sum, but range from consecutive to very far from consecutive. https://youtu.be/oqMl5CRoFdk

Comment: If you know the first and the last element , you can calculate the sum given that the entries are consecutive integers and compare this with the given sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you got me to actually LOL with that link. Optimization I arrived at that I think is a fair balance is to look at the first number, add to it the number of items in the set, and compare that with the last number. If they aren't equal I can stop. Then I can use the same method on the 2nd number in the set and the 2nd to last, moving toward the center of the set. The worst performance would be if the number in the middle is non-consecutive - and odds are good that won't happen, so it should be quite a lot faster. I'll have to run some tests to see if there's a measurable advantage.